# Can I upload a directory to a remote node via watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a cucumber test that uploads a directory by entering the directory path into the file field. It works perfectly fine when I run the test on my machine but I'm getting the following error when I try to run it against my selenium grid setup:

```
you may only upload files: "/cucumber_tests/temp/uploads/Cuke1477494492767281" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
  (eval):1:in 'process_watir_call'
```

Full backtrace:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.1.1/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:1052:in 'instance_eval'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:432:in 'send_keys_to_element'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:146:in 'send_keys'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:319:in 'block in send_keys'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:621:in 'element_call'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:319:in 'send_keys'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/file_field.rb:24:in 'value='
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/file_field.rb:13:in 'set'
(eval):1:in 'process_watir_call'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.1.1/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:1052:in 'instance_eval'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.1.1/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:1052:in 'process_watir_call'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.1.1/lib/page-object/platforms/watir_webdriver/page_object.rb:846:in 'file_field_value_set'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.1.1/lib/page-object/accessors.rb:1021:in 'block in file_field'
```

My code pretty much looks like this:

```
@browser.file_field(id: "assets").send_keys "/cucumber_tests/temp/uploads/Cuke1477494492767281"
```

Again, I'd like to emphasize that this works perfectly fine on my machine but not on the remote node. Also, single file uploads are fine for me on both my machine and on the grid. I'm wondering if any of you have had luck uploading directories on remote nodes or know if it's even possible (even if I have to install more gems). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the absolute path to the file:

```
File.expand_path("/cucumber_tests/temp/uploads/Cuke1477494492767281")
```

Unless you are trying to upload something from your local computer to a remote computer via Watir. That you can't do.

No, Selenium & Watir are not designed to upload directories. You could loop through files, but they wouldn't be in a subdirectory.

```
Dir["/path/to/files/*"].each do |file|
  @browser.file_field(id: "assets").set File.expand_path(file)
  @browser.form.button.click
end
```

Comment: Did you mean directory? It's very much possible to upload a _file_ from my local computer to a remote computer (and I'm able to do that without a problem). It's being able to upload a _directory_ from a local computer to a remote computer that I haven't been able to do.